# How to a Widget in Android Automative OS

Tags: android, android-automotive, aaos

I am making an App, it called Home (main App). In this app, I want to create a Widget to show somethings but it seems Android Automative OS does not support Widget anymore. Is there any ways to create a Widget for other App in Android Automative ?

I tried Jetpack Glance (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/glance) but Android Automative does not support Widget as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[Android CDD](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/14/android-14-cdd#382_widgets) requires `android.software.app_widgets` feature if the device support third-party app widgets.

If you check this feature by using `adb shell pm list features` on AAOS emulator of Android Studio, there is no this feature. So, looks like AAOS do not support widget in general.